# how to redirect with session_start on top of page php

Tags: php, session

i am checking the user login and password on a separate page on top of which i have

```
session_start();
```

Now if the user gives wrong credentials then i want him to go back but redirect is not working it gives error headers already sent and that is because of session_start() . what could be the best way of doing it. thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's because of the `session_start()`. Maybe you have a space somewhere at the beginning of your file, or you are outputting something before the `header()`?

Comment: Why do session_start send error headers? Pretty sure I have redirected after session_start several times before...

Comment: As TJHeuvel answered use output buffering via ob_start() to stop anything being sent to the browser until your processing logic has completed, if there is a redirect in there it will still work as no data will be sent until you close the output buffer via ob_flush().

Comment: @Svish - Sessions which use cookies there is data sent relating to the cookies in the header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First check if there is not any space before session_start

or you can also do this

on start before session_start write "ob_start();"   and on the page end write "ob_flush();"

This will help

Answer (score 1):

Use [ob_start](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to buffer the output. This prevents `session_start` from sending headers right away, and makes it wait untill the end of the request.

Answer (score 0):

A simple alternative is to use the following piece of HTML code, placed in the `head` element of your HTML output.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://google.com">
```

Answer (score 0):

check if there aren't white spaces or new line before php start tag or some echo...
you can try to use ob_start

```
<?php 
    ob_start(); 

    session_start();
    // code  

    //Flush the buffer to screen
    ob_end_flush(); 
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php